# Storing SQLite in Memory Database with ADM-ZIP (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, sqlite, adm-zip

I'm trying to use the `sqlite3` module to create an in memory SQLite database and the `adm-zip` module to save it into a zip file. So far I have been able to create an in memory database and add data to it, but I have been unsuccessful in finding a way to store it in a zip made through `adm-zip` as it requires either a file, buffer or string.

My question is this: does the `sqlite3` module even support storing or saving as a buffer? If it doesn't then what would be an advisable solution for storing temporary files in Node.js when the script is used as both a requirable module and a command line script?

I've included the code I've been using to test with below and a cloneable gist.

**main.js**

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    admzip = require('adm-zip'),
    sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose(),
    zip = new admzip(),
    db = new sqlite3.Database('test.sqlite');
    // db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');

db.serialize(function() {

    db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);');
    db.run('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO test(name) VALUES ("neogeek");');

});

zip.addFile('README.md', '#SQLite3 + ADM-ZIP Test');

// zip.addFile('db.sqlite', db);

db.close();

fs.writeFileSync('test.zip', zip.toBuffer(), 'utf8');
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "sqlite3": "3.0.2",
        "adm-zip": "0.4.4"
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/neogeek/70c80c7ddaf998bee4bd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While continuing to pursue an answer for this question I stumbled upon the npm module `temp` and was able to put together a workable solution as detailed below.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    temp = require('temp').track(),
    admzip = require('adm-zip'),
    sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose(),
    zip = new admzip(),
    tempdb = temp.openSync('db.sqlite'),
    db = new sqlite3.Database(tempdb.path);

db.serialize(function() {

    db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);');
    db.run('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO test(name) VALUES ("neogeek");');

});

zip.addFile('README.md', '#SQLite3 + ADM-ZIP Test');

db.close(function () {

    zip.addFile('test.sqlite', fs.readFileSync(tempdb.path));

    fs.writeFileSync('test.zip', zip.toBuffer(), 'utf8');

});
```

I included the temp module and made sure to activate automatic cleanup of any temporary files created with`.track()`.

```
temp = require('temp').track(),
```

I then created a new file to store the sqlite database in.

```
tempdb = temp.openSync('db.sqlite'),
```

Finally I moved the writing of both the sqlite file to the in memory zip and the final output zip file into the sqlite close method callback.

```
db.close(function () {

    zip.addFile('test.sqlite', fs.readFileSync(tempdb.path));

    fs.writeFileSync('test.zip', zip.toBuffer(), 'utf8');

});
```

https://gist.github.com/neogeek/70c80c7ddaf998bee4bd